JacobianMatrix function flattens input in column order
The JacobianMatrix function appears to flatten its input in column order. Both of the following queries (Wolfram Alpha syntax) give the same result:
Q1: "JacobianMatrix of {{a_1+a_2, a_1+ a_2, b_1+b_2}, {x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2, z_1+z_2}} with respect to {a_1, a_2}"
Q2: "JacobianMatrix of Flatten[{{a_1+a_2, a_1+ a_2, b_1+b_2}, {x_1+x_2, y_1+y_2, z_1+z_2}}, {2,1}] with respect to {a_1, a_2}"
Note that the Flatten function by default appears to flatten in row-major order, while Q2 enforces column-major order.
Is there a mathematical reason for using column-major flattening in the JacobianMatrix case but row-major flattening in general?
EDIT: The unambiguous Mathematica expressions according to the Wolfram Alpha translations are:
Q = ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"][{{Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[b, 1] + Subscript[b, 2]}, {Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[y, 1] + Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[z, 1] + Subscript[z, 2]}}, {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}]

P = ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"][{Flatten[{{Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[a, 1] + Subscript[a, 2], Subscript[b, 1] + Subscript[b, 2]}, {Subscript[x, 1] + Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[y, 1] + Subscript[y, 2], Subscript[z, 1] + Subscript[z, 2]}}, {2, 1}]}, {Subscript[a, 1], Subscript[a, 2]}]


Wolfram|Alpha is off-topic here. Can you re-phrase your question in correct Mathematica syntax?  As it is, I find it hard to figure out what you're asking.

Sorry for posting an off-topic question. I do not have access to Mathematica, but I have added the Wolfram Alpha translations to Mathematica (which are as expected but which WA itself curiously enough does not understand---it needs the natural language query). The question is simply about how JacobianMatrix deals with multidimensional inputs. It looks like it flattens them to a regular vector before computing the answer. The flattening appears to happen in column-major order, which is not the default of the Flatten function.

Well, I fail to understand the question. According to my test (both in my PC and Wolfram cloud), the 2 lines of the code has returned unevaluated: https://i.sstatic.net/jt63J8QF.png  It's not too surprising because according to the document ResourceFunction["JacobianMatrix"] is not defined for matrix: https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/JacobianMatrix/ What ouput are you expecting here?

Thanks! So Mathematica behaves according to its documentation.  Wolfram Alpha however does evaluate the Q1 and Q2 expressions (just try it!) and claims that they are equivalent to the Q and P Mathematica expressions. Moreover, WA's behavior is not unreasonable. In, e.g., machine learning multidimensional arrays are regarded as flattened before taking the Jacobian matrix. I assumed that Mathematica does the same and wanted to know the exact semantics.

I think Wolfram|Alpha has simply done a bad job in interpreting the natural language input here. (Not too surprising, and that's why we don't often use Wolfram|Alpha for serious programming. ) Then, is this the output you want?: https://i.sstatic.net/YjLmz6ux.png

Yes, that is the output I want. So in Mathematica one has to flatten the input explicitly, that makes sense. Thanks again, the question is fully answered (I would upvote, but apparently there are no upvote buttons for new users)!
